# Kotlin libraries syntax not colored

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

When I browse through libraries in my project the Kotlin ones are not syntax colored. For example Java:

[image]

And here Kotlin:

[image]

What is the setting I can change to color it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the newest IntelliJ release they provided a source code for kotlin, which resulted in a colorfull code.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Kotlin IDE plugin installed?
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin

Plugins -> search repositories -> Kotlin

Comment: Yes it is. It only happens to the libraries

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, the Kotlin code has some coloring, so the syntax highlighting is working, just maybe not the colors you want. You can adjust the syntax coloring in your preferences in Editor -> Color Scheme -> Kotlin. (Java and Kotlin have separate Color Scheme settings.)

Comment: Kotlin didn't use have its sources attached. While now it has it there is no problem anymore